# How to use Prettier on Bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, prettier

I am trying to use code formatter, Prettier, on a Bitbucket pipeline but all I get is a "prettier command not found".

This is my pipeline configuration:

```
mage: node:latest
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          caches:
          - node
          script:
          - npm install prettier
          - prettier --check
```

Is it even possible to run it through pipelines or would have to forcefully do it locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you follow the documentation https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html

- install prettier in your repo

  npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier

"--save-dev" because the production will not need prettier to serve your application

- add your rules in .prettierrc.json file in the root of the repo
- in the pipeline use

  npx prettier --check .

> What is that npx thing? npx ships with npm and lets you run locally installed tools. We’ll leave off the npx part for brevity throughout the rest of this file!
> Note: If you forget to install Prettier first, npx will temporarily download the latest version. That’s not a good idea when using Prettier, because we change how code is formatted in each release! It’s important to have a locked down version of Prettier in your package.json. And it’s faster, too.

When you have installed prettier in your repo, you can even add pre-commit hooks to modify the staged files before pushing.